# Can I Rename the Title of Command Windows from the Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

We have several command line apps that are launched from the Task Scheduler. They all have the title 'taskeng.exe'. Is there a way to rename the windows, to make them easier to identify?

We're running the exes directly, not via a batch file, so the TITLE command isn't easily available. I prefer not to use a batch file to launch the exes.

Thank you

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can I rename the title of command wWindows from the Task Scheduler?

Use the `TN` option:

- /TN   A name for the task

---

#### Examples

> Create a task to run at 11 pm every weekday
>
> `SCHTASKS /Create /SC weekly /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN MyDailyBackup
>   /ST 23:00 /TR c:\backup.cmd /RU MyDomain\MyLogin /RP MyPassword`
>
> Now delete the task:
>
> `SCHTASKS /Delete /TN "MyDailyBackup" /f`
>
> Create a one-off task to run a script at exactly12 midday:
>
> `SCHTASKS /create /tn "once only" /tr "\"c:\my folder\one.cmd\"
>   arguments" /sc ONCE /sd 12/29/2014 /st 12:00`
>
> Create a daily task to run a script at 5 pm:
>
> `SCHTASKS /create /tn "My Script" /tr "\"c:\my folder\script.cmd\"
>   arguments" /sc daily /sd 12/29/2014 /st 17:00`
>
> Create a task ready to run on demand - this is done by creating a task
>   scheduled far in the past:
>
> `SCHTASKS /create /tn "On demand demo" /tr "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
>   /sc ONCE /sd 01/01/1910 /st 00:00`

Source [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [schtasks](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html) - Create / edit a Scheduled Job/Task. The job can be created on the local or a remote computer.

Comment: That's fantastic - thank you. Is there any way to do this via the Task Manager GUI?

Comment: Not as far as I know :/

Comment: I'm running with highest privileges and all I see is Administrator: taskeng.exe in the Title